# Add an iCalendar feed for chat events

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

It would be convenient to have notifications about upcoming chat events appear in whatever system users normally use.  The simplest way of doing this would be to provide an [iCalendar feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) of upcoming events, much like there are various RSS links throughout the site.

Ideally there would be multiple links, like there are multiple RSS links, e.g.

- One for all events across all chat rooms.
- One for all events within a specific room.
- One for each repeating event.

This would make it easy to remember when there was an upcoming event (because it would be in the user's calendar like anything else), and also help increase prominence of new events (to users that have shown an interest in previous ones).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a pretty good idea. Maybe the last bullet should just be "per event", but... good idea.

After a brief refresher on iCal, this is now in place. You can export events for the entire chat, per-room, or an individual event. Recurrence is included, etc.

Look for the "export" links.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't think of the case where someone might want to click on the link and have the one item added to their calendar, rather than subscribe to something that would change.